# Or operator do not work as expected laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

It seems very basic **but** as mentioned in this link or something like this: https://laravel-news.com/blade-or-operator I expect that:

```
{{ $title or 'login' }}
```

have to be compiled like this:

```
if( isset($title) )
{
    echo $title;
}
else {
    echo 'login';
}
```

or in short way that's equivalent this:

```
isset($title) ? $title : 'login'
```

Well, but when I use this, laravel send me an error says:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable: title (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\site\resources\views\layouts\auth.blade.php) (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\site\resources\views\layouts\auth.blade.php)
>   Previous exceptions
>
> ```
> Undefined variable: title (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\site\resources\views\layouts\auth.blade.php) (0)
> Undefined variable: title (0)
> ```

that means something is wrong with this.

Do you know what could be wrong in my code or configuration?

***Thanks in Advance***

Comment: What version of Laravel and what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson I mentioned laravel version in my question title and this is `5.7.19` and my php version is `7.2.9`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the laravel new says:

> In the next major release, Laravel 5.7 removes the Blade “or” Operator. Andrew Brown submitted a PR for Laravel 5.7 to Remove Blade Defaults from the framework, due to the new Null Coalesce operator available in PHP 7.

Please look at once.
https://laravel-news.com/blade-templates-null-coalesce-operator

You can use.

`{{ $title ?? 'login' }}`

Answer (score 1):

better to used [`??(null coalescing operator)`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_coalescing_operator.htm) in **php 7**

```
{{ $title ?? 'login' }}
```

> It is used to replace the ternary operation in conjunction with
>   isset() function. The Null coalescing operator returns its first
>   operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second
>   operand.

Answer (score 1):

The `or` Operator

The Blade "or" operator has been removed in favor of PHP's built-in `??` "null coalesce" operator, which has the same purpose and functionality:

```
// Laravel 5.6...
{{ $foo or 'default' }}

// Laravel 5.7...
{{ $foo ?? 'default' }}
```

You can use like: `{{ $title ?? 'login' }}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting such an error, then your `$title` variable is most likely undefined so double check your code. On a related note, Laravel's blade system doesn't seem to compile that `or` operator into what you are expecting anymore. Check your cached view file and you would most likely see something like

`<?php echo e($title or 'login'); ?>`

instead of

`<?php echo e(isset($title ) ? $title : 'login'); ?>`

which is what you would get with older versions of Laravel, leading to a buggy result (the first one evaluates to a boolean value. The second one returns either the value of $title or the string 'login', just like what you were expecting). That's why it's recommended to use the null coalesce (??) operator now when using Laravel versions 5.7 and up.